# Reading a specific row from an Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm writing a song lyrics search engine using Python. The target is for a user to enter a string and to retrive the x closest songs that in a database that contains all the words in the string that he entered.
I've build a DB of x songs and mapped all the words of all those songs into an Excel file.
Because the DB is suppose to be very large I dont want to hold a matrix with all the values that I need, and I'm trying not to load the Excel file to my program.
There is any build function to search a word in the Excel file and then hold the whole row of that word, without loading the whole Exel file? for example:

```
  A            B         C                  N
```

### | wordName | song 1 | song 2 | ..... | song x |

### 1|  ready   |   1    |   0    | ...

### 2| action   |   1    |   1    | ...

.
.
n| many more words

The table above is saved in the Excel file

- A,B,C ... N are the columns names in Excel
- 1,2 are Excel's rows numbers
- The user entered the string "ready action" so I want to hold the first and second rows.

I need to access the words 'ready' and 'action' without loading the whole table.
I can't use 'fileName[A1]' for accessing data because I don't know where in the table the word is located.

Is there and way to do it?
thanks.

I ecpect to return the songs that has all the words the user entered.

Comment: please reformat question so that it is readble.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the size of your Excel file. I am assuming it is too big to load it within a reasonable time or it cannot fit into RAM. I am also assuming that the second column of the file can be loaded in full (if not, see below).

### First search the right row, then fetch the whole row

Pandas could help you read only the second column of the file and check which row contains the word you are looking for.

```py
import pandas as pd

words = ["ready", "action"]
# or do
# words = input("Please enter some words, separated by spaces...").split()
file = "/path/to/file.xlsx"

# First fetch the wordName column to see which rows we need.
df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols=["wordName"])
df_selection = df[df["wordName"].isin(words)]

# Fetch the complete rows of the selected rows.
df_selection_whole_rows = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=lambda x: x not in df_selection.index.values.astype(int)[0])
```

### If wordNames columns does not fit in memory or is too large

Do the above, but in steps where `skiprows` is used to loop through the file in chunks:

```py
chunk_size = 500  # Can be any size you deem acceptable.
chunk = 0
while True:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols=["wordName"], skiprows=chunk * chunk_size)
    df_selection = df[df["wordName"].isin(words)]

    df_selection_whole_rows = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=lambda x: x not in 
    df_selection.index.values.astype(int)[0])

    # break out of the loop if end of file is reached.
    if len(df) < chunk_size:  
        break
    else:
        chunk += 1
```

disclaimer: untested.